# Java generics, constraining the type to the 'self' type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

This is a rather specialized question and I doubt there is a solution.

I've got a type hierarchy like A {}, B extends A{}, C extends A {}. A defines an abstract method `<T extends A> T scale(double v)`.

The problem is that T is not anchored and you can assign the result to any type.

The solved this problem in enum (and that is why I think there is no solution) by declaring the 'self' type as a generic parameter:

```
 class A<T extends A<T>> { T scale(double v) { ... ;} }
 class B extends A<B> {}
 class C extends A<C> {}
```

Another solution would be to write the scale method in each subclass:

```
 class A<T extends A<T>> { A scale(double v){...} }
 class B extends A<B> { B scale(double v) { super.scale(v);}}
 class C extends A<C> { C scale( double v) { super.scale(v);} }
```

However, this is all ugly and lots of work.

I do not see why the compiler could not solve this problem. (I am probably missing something.)  What I would like is something like this:

```
 class A { this scale(double v); }
```

Now this clearly does not work but I wonder if people found interesting generic hacks to constrain a generic return type or a generic parameter to the 'current' type the compiler observes.

Comment: "I do not see why the compiler could not solve this problem." Because the compiler team has a budget. They can't implement *every feature*.

Comment: First of all, the compiler developers can only add features backed by the standard. On the other hand, if a feature gets added to the specification, all compiler vendors must implement it. This, plus all compatibility and documentation concerns, is the reason why extending the standard is a long, formal process. You can file an RFE and see how it works.

Comment: "The solved this problem in enum (and that is why I think there is no solution) by declaring the 'self' type as a generic parameter" Are you sure this does what you think? Note that it is perfectly legal to declare `class D extends A<C> {}` given your declarations here. How is the `scale()` method going to safely get a value of type `T` to return?

Comment: I think you're needing this for some kinda pattern, can you disclose it to us so that we can help you with your specific need? The main problem here is that the compiler __can't__ solve the problem because you can't guarantee you're actually returning `this` from your `scale` method, so how's your `A` class supposed to know how to make new instances of `B` or `C` from within its `scale` method? That'd be only possible if you actually return `this` from a supertype, but as said, you can't guarantee the compiler you're always returnint `this`... and if you are, why are you doing so?

Comment: At any moment in time the compiler has a known type for a variable, this type is used to create the actual the signature for calling methods and using fields. I.e. if I do: `A b = new B();` then my desired `THIS` type would be `A` but if I do `B b=new B()` it should be `B` for `THIS b.scale(.5)`. If I do `Object b=new B();` it should be `Object`.